# Simple interval timer for Android

Tags: android, timer

I need a simple timer app that would do just this: ring a bell (play a sound from an MP3 file preferably, but a build-in single-ring bell sound would do, it just has to be short and gentle, not an alarm) once every N minutes in a loop before I stop it. It must not require any intervention to stop ringing - just ring a bell and go on counting to the next time to ring.

It would also be great (yet is not necessary) if I could specify an irregular sequence of time intervals like 1 minute - bell - 15 minutes - bell - 7 minutes - bell - etc.

It should work nicely in background in parallel with media players like VLC but if it doesn't this is a tolerable flaw.

Most of the timer apps I could find in the Play store either focus on exercises or on meditation. Exercise-focused mostly are over-bloated, cost money and won't let you specify sounds. Meditation-focused often lack loop function.

The task seems simple and I can write such an app myself yet I would prefer to use an existing free app if it already exists.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this app :

Alarm Clock with Missions & Loud Ringtones -Alarmy

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=droom.sleepIfUCan&hl=en

Answer (score 1):

for anything you want to automate on your mobile phone, I can highly recommend you
Automate for Android. It is a small, yet powerful visual scripting app that allows you to perform any task you want:
https://llamalab.com/automate/
This isn't the actual answer, as you still need to program it yourself. But along the way of scripting your timer, you'll discover so much more possibilities this little app holds.
Good luck!